# Modelset Factory displays a choice fields instead of an input field

Tags: django, django-models

Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    conent = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to="post_pics")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)


        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Post, through='PostTag')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class PostTag(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Forms.py

```
class PostUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'conent', 'image']

class TagUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PostTag
        fields = ['tag']

TagUpdateFormSet = modelformset_factory(PostTag, form=TagUpdateForm)
```

Views.py

```
@login_required
def updateView(request, pk):
    template_name = 'project/post_update.html'
    heading_message = 'Tags'
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form1 = PostUpdateForm(instance=Post.objects.filter(id=pk).first())
        form2 = TagUpdateFormSet(queryset=PostTag.objects.filter(article=Post.objects.filter(id=pk).first()))

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = PostUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=Post.objects.filter(id=pk).first())
        form2 = TagUpdateFormSet(request.POST, queryset=PostTag.objects.filter(article=Post.objects.filter(id=pk).first()))
        if form1.is_valid():
            invalid = True
            for formz in form2:
                if formz.is_valid() == False:
                    invalid = False
                    break
            if invalid:
                postform = form1.save(commit=False)
                postform.author = request.user
                postform.save()
                for forms in form2:
                    data = forms.cleaned_data.get('tag')
                    if data:
                        returnedTag, created1 = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name = data)
                        link, created2 = PostTag.objects.get_or_create(article = postform, tag = returnedTag)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/forum/post/%s/' %(postform.id))

    return render(request, 'project/post_update.html', {'form': form1, 'form2': form2})
```

template

```
{% extends "template/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    {% load static %}
    <div class="container form-section s-yellow section">
        <form method="POST" action="" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-container">
                <legend class="form-top"></legend>
                <div class="form1">
                    {{ form|crispy }}
                </div>
                <div class="form2 form-group">
                        {{ form2.management_form }}
                        {% for formz in form2 %}
                        <div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    {{formz }}
                                    <div class="">
                                        <button type="button" class="add-form-row">+</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
            </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I want to let the user be able to edit all tags in a post, however when i display the tags they show up as choice field that lets the user choose from already existing tags and they can't type a new one.

Is there a way to change the choice field to an input field where the original value is the tag originaly entered.

I tried edditing the 'tag' field to a charfield above the meta tag in the form, but then i was getting an input field with the choice field value (eg 4, 6, 10,) instead of the actual text.

I know the saving part doesnt work, but i need to figure out a way to get the fields dispalyed properly

Btw are there any tutorials for a database structure like this? It's hard to find examples where one table links to 2 others.

Comment: Let me ask you a more fundemental question: _why_ are you implementing a many-to-many relationship **manually**?

Comment: Yeah, you were right. I used a many-to-many field in my models and managed to fix it and shorten the code a little bit. I didn't understand what exactly the manytomany field was used for initially but now i do.